# integrate mixpanel on symfony2 project without composer

Tags: php, symfony, mixpanel

i can not to integrate mixpanel tracking with php on a symfony2 project without composer.

I have download the folder mixpanel-php and put it on my project.

i'm calling it like that:

```
require 'mixpanel-php/lib/Mixpanel.php';
$mp = Mixpanel::getInstance("MY_TOKEN");
$mp->track("index page");
```

but it does not work an the response is

```
Fatal error: Class 'WittPic\WebBundle\Controller\Mixpanel' not found in C:\wamp\www\wittpic\httpdocs\src\WittPic\WebBundle\Controller\PublicController.php on line 22
```

Comment: why not use https://github.com/gordalina/GordalinaMixpanelBundle where all the hard work is done for you?

Comment: but how to install it without composer?

Comment: why dont you want to use composer?

Comment: is not that i don't want to, i don't know if installing composer now will impact on my route system. i have inherite a project created without composer

Comment: just use `composer.phar require xxxpackagexxx` and it wont effect anything else.  https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

Comment: how to add composer to a project wich was originaly developed not usign it. Is it secure? how will afect to my dependecies? now i use a file called autoload.php wich manage routing and dependecies

Comment: Composer can be globally installed.  Its not tied to any project. https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel doesn't use namepsaces, so all its classes loaded into root namespace. You have to tell PHP to load `Mixpanel` class from root namespace by prefixing it with  backslash `\`

```
$mp = \Mixpanel::getInstance("MY_TOKEN");
```

Comment: Using this:
require __DIR__.'\..\..\..\..\vendor\autoload.php';
        $mp = \Mixpanel::getInstance("MY_TOKEN");
        $mp->track("click index");
I don't track anything and no errors generated